# How can I log/read a string in a bash script without executing it?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm starting to learn how to write shell scripts. I have them all placed in a folder 'personal-scripts' in my home directory. They are starting to add up though. To solve this, I am attempting to create a script that loops over the directory and gives me a brief sentence about what each script does.

For now I can only output the script location and names via:

**scriptsinfo**

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ~/personal-scripts/*
do
  echo $filename
done
```

Since I don't want to go back and update this file manually, I want to place the about sentence inside each other script either as a comment or string variable that can be evaluated.

How can I read the contents of each other script in the folder and output their string/info about what they do in this script?

Comment: You mean there is a comment in each script such as ``# about: ...`` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still deciding how to work it out so it can be placed anywhere with any kind of characters for easier parsing, but I think just making it the next line right below the #!/bin/bash comment would be easy to grab right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the description on each second line of your script, (after `#!/bin/bash` then let use `sed -n "2p" $filename`in your script. You can also add a separator between each script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ~/personal-scripts/*
do
  echo "---------------------"
  echo $filename
  echo "---------------------"
  sed -n "2p" $filename
done
```

The alternative is to put the description anywhere, in a line starting by *e.g* `# about:` then you  can `grep` it:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ~/personal-scripts/*
do
  echo "---------------------"
  echo $filename
  echo "---------------------"
  grep "# about:" $filename | sed 's/# about://'
done
```

The `| sed 's/# about://'` is there to keep the description only.

Comment: Thanks for this! : )

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `head` command, which prints the first `n` lines of a file.

**test.sh**

```
# this is about line
# date is 14-9-2017

script data
..
..
```

**~# head -n 2 test.sh**

```
# this is about line
# date is 14-9-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a comment inside all your scripts with a specific pattern  such as

> #info : This script runs daily

Then you can simply `grep` for the pattern and append to the name of the script in each line.

```
for filename in ~/personal-scripts/*
do
echo "$i : $(grep '#info' $i)"
done
```